# PHP: Edit existing PDF (font size, color, font family)

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

Is it possible to edit an existing PDF with PHP?
I already worked a lot with FPDF.

But now I need to edit the font size, font color and font family with PHP.
Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Possible, "more or less", but it is either exceedingly difficult or expensive. Originally PDF's were only made to produce output on paper (see: Postscript), and this still makes editing them very awkward.